# python print() doesnt output what I expect

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I made a small web-crawler in one function, **upso_final**.

If I `print(upso_final())`, I get 15 lists that include title, address, phone #.  However, I want to print out only title, so I made variable **title** a global string.  When I print it, I get only 1 title, the last one in the run. I want to get all 15 titles.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import scrapy
import pymysql

def upso_final(page=1):
    def upso_from_page(url):
        html = fetch_page(url)
        sel = Selector(text=html)

        global title,address,phone
        title = sel.css('h1::text').extract()
        address = sel.css('address::text').extract()
        phone = sel.css('.mt1::text').extract()
        return {
            'title' : title,
            'address' : address,
            'phone' : phone
        }
    def upso_list_from_listpage(url):
        html = fetch_page(url)
        sel = Selector(text=html)
        upso_list = sel.css('.title_list::attr(href)').extract()

        return upso_list  
    def fetch_page(url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.text      

    list_url = "http://yp.koreadaily.com/list/list.asp?page={0}&bra_code=LA&cat_code=L020502&strChar=&searchField=&txtAddr=&txtState=&txtZip=&txtSearch=&sort=N".format(page)
    upso_lists = upso_list_from_listpage(list_url)
    upsos = [upso_from_page(url) for url in upso_lists]
    return upsos

upso_final()

print (title,address,phone)
```

Comment: Since you only have one `print`, and it's not in a loop, you're only going to get one line of output. Your logic needs some work.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're confused about passing values back from a function.

**upso_from_page** finds each of the 15 records in turn, placing the desired information in the global variables (generally a bad design).  However, the only time you print any results is after you've found all 15.  Since your logic has each record overwriting the previous one, you print only the last one you found.

It appears that **upso_final** accumulates the list and returns it, but you ignore that return value.  Instead, try this in your main program:

```
upso_list = upso_final()

for upso in upso.list:
    print (upso)
```

This should give you a 3-item dictionary for each **upso** record; from there, you can learn the referencing and format to your taste.

---

AN alternate solution is to print each record as you find it, from within **upso_from_page**, but your overall design suggests that's not what you want.

Comment: Oh... Thank you so much. I got it now,